# Conditionally executing some part of python code as 2.x in a 3.x program

Tags: python

There is an option of `__future__` to import modules from python `3.x` into `2.x` venv.
Is there a similar option that allows 2.x code to be run in 3.x venv.

Some thing like

```
__use2.x__:
   #2.x code block

#back to 3.x code
```

This is to be used to merge codes from different versions while upgrading to a higher level of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several modules that may prove helpful (hard to say which is best or how to do it, without knowing anything about the code you are talking about). But for starters I'd recommend:

- [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html)
- [futurize](http://python-future.org/automatic_conversion.html)

Comment: Thanks @WillMonge:  yes but this all enforces a pre-translation - what if there are some modules being developed in 2.x and some in 3.x and we want to use 2.x modules in 3.x code with 3.x venv for some reason without having to translate. How reliable is this translation using 2to3 / futurize - are there some known issues that might give us some road-bumps.